# Unit test tools for iPhone development with Xcode

Tags: unit-testing, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, mocking

When developing iPhone apps with Xcode 3.2.1/Objective C, which unit test tools are recommended?
I am new to the iPhone OS platform, and I am interested in your best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended testing frameork is OCUnit, which ships with Xcode. You will also find that the [Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/) has a great many useful tools for testing OS X and iPhone applications, including UI testing on both platforms.

For mock objects, I personally recommend [OCMock](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/).